# next() middleware not working with token authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, middleware

I am doing account registration using email authentication, I'm sending a token on the URL, then I use useParams to get the token from the URL and pass it to the backend to finally validate the user's account.

The issue is that on the authentication middleware of the backend, the next() callback is not continuing with the process.

The middleware resolves/decodes the token **succesfully** (because it's showing the user id stored inside of it) and when next() is called, everything stops, doesn't give any errors, nothing. This happens when I make a GET request, if I make a POST request it returns that the token is not valid, which is not true.

Front-end request:

```
const Confirmation = () => {
    const [popMessage, setPopMessage] = useState('');

    let params = useParams("/confirm/:token");
    const {token} = params;

    const confirmAcc = async () =>{
        try {
            const config = {
                headers:{
                    'x-auth-token': token,
                }
            }
            await axios.get('/api/auth/confirm/', config)
            .catch(err=>{
                console.error(err.response);
            })
            setPopMessage('Your account has been confirmed');
        //    setTimeout(() => { window.location.href = '/login';}, 3500);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response.data);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Back-end router:

```
router.get('/confirm/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Im here!!')
    try {
        console.log('Im here too!!')
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
        console.log('user', user)
        await user.update({ confirmed: true });
        sendEmail(user.email, user.name, "welcome");
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(401).send('your email token is invalid');
      return;
    }
});
```

Middleware 'auth':

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).send('No token, authorization denied ');
    }
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
        console.log('decoded:', decoded)
        req.user = decoded.user;
        next();
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(401).send('Token is not valid');
    }
}
```

The weirdest thing: It only happens with this router the rest of the application works fine with the same exact code. I would really appreciate if anyone can share any ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing I see is that your `router.get("/confirm", ...)` route doesn't send any sort of response to the request when it's successful.  It just sends the email, but doesn't send anything back to the client as an http response.  The `auth()` middleware looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you sure that `jwt.verify(token, ...)` decodes to a whole user object?

Comment: Also, the `axios()` call in the client code calls `setPopMessage('Your account has been confirmed');`, even when there was an error.  But, in the success case, because the `axios()` call never completes because you never send a response from the server, that `await axios()` will just sit forever (unless there's an error).  So, you need to send a response from the client `res.send("ok")` or something.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried your ideas but didn't work I ended up fixing it differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the type of request: I changed to a PUT req and sending an empty body on the req. That fixed it, here the code:

```
const Confirmation = () => {
    const [popMessage, setPopMessage] = useState('');

    let params = useParams("/confirm/:token");
    const {token} = params;

    const confirmAcc = async () =>{
        try {
            const config = {
                headers:{
                    'x-auth-token': token,
                }
            }
           // here, empty body and PUT req.
            const body = null
            axios.put('/api/auth/confirm/',body, config)
            .catch(err=>{
                console.error(err.response);
            });
            setPopMessage('Your account has been confirmed');
            setTimeout(() => { window.location.href = '/login';}, 3500);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response.data);
            return;
        }
      };
```

Comment: Your code still says "Your account has been confirmed" even when it has not been confirmed (when the axios call returned an error).

Comment: Thanks, I changed that message to be sent from the backend if everything goes well